# Does "$X$ is $Y$" imply "$Y$ is $X$"?

Tags: terminology, definition

This is a funny story with my friend.

My friend had this t-shirt with the saying "less is more" (exactly like this image)

[image]

This was our conversation.

Me: "If they made the word less be less, they should also have made the word more be more, right?"

Friend: "Actually less is more so more is less so it makes sense to have the word more be less"

Me: "Actually less is more doesn’t imply more is less"

These were our arguments

**Friend**

$X$ is $Y$ means $X = Y$. Therefore, $Y = X$, so $Y$ is $X$. Hence $X$ is $Y \implies Y$ is $X$.

**Me**

[image]

Let $A = X$ and $B = Y$. It follows that $X$ is $Y$. However, we can have a point inside $Y$ but outside $X$ so $Y$ is not necessarily $X$. Hence $X$ is $Y$ doesn't imply $Y$ is $X$. For example, Alkali is Base does not imply Base is Alkali.

So our arguments come down to the definition of "is". What is the mathematical definition of "is" or is it an ambiguous term? Does $X$ is $Y$ have a fixed mathematical meaning or is it open to interpretation?

Comment: The word "is" is an ambiguous term. In the context of sets I think you are discerning between "equal to" versus "subset of."

Comment: Rain is water, but water is not necessarily rain.

Comment: I hesitate to take this question seriously, but I would say that there are lots of cases where "is" means inclusion, and many others where it means equality. English and other natural languages (I imagine) are just imprecise like that. I don't think you can reliably make a general blanket statement.

Comment: well i just asked it because we had a pretty heated argument lol, anyways

Comment: As Bill Clinton said, "It depends on what the definition of 'is' is."

Comment: It is safe to say that all blanket statements are dangerous.

Comment: @Michael I see what you did there.

Comment: 'is' is a verb, but not every verb is 'is' :)

Comment: in most contexts, this sentence is used with implicit subject, so the meaning depends a lot on that. "less [something] is more [something else]"

Comment: Grass is green. Green is not grass.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P8IYKxpqG0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say that $2=1+1$ we mean equality, a special meaning of the word "is".  When we say every cat is a mammal, we mean the subset relation.  Or perhaps we mean something less mathematical, like a notion of "intensionality", or some fuzzy natural language meaning--but whatever, the point is that this version of "is" is different from the first.

Another version of "is" is the "is of predication".  To say "the ball is red" is to predicate of the ball some property like redness.  One could argue this is coincident with the idea of the subset relation, or argue that it's not, this is a philosophical argument.

When you say "More is less" you mean something much less precise than any of these things.  That is something more like a metaphorical or slang use of the word.  It means to communicate something like "Doing more produces a lesser net profit" or some such abbreviated and vague sentiment.

But in any case, this expression is not a mathematical expression.

Comment: And here we see an example as "less is more".  My last paragraph and your last paragraph ultimately say the same thing. :D

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing Former President Clinton, "it depends on what the definition of 'is' is".

Spoken (or even written) English is ambiguous.  As Brian Tung indicated in a comment, the verb "to be" in English can be translated into mathematical English as either an inclusion, or as an equality (roughly speaking—there are other meanings).  This ambiguity means that a statement like "Less is More" can be interpreted in two mathematically distinct ways.

- **Inclusion:** If "is" is interpreted as an inclusion, then the statement "$X$ is $Y$" can be understood to mean "every example of $X$ is an example of $Y$, but not necessarily the other way around".  That is, $X \subseteq Y$.
  For example:

  - a square *is* a rectangle.
  - an interval of the form $(a,b)$ *is* an open set, or
  - a human *is* a mammal.
- **Equality:** If "is" is interpreted as equality, then the statement "$X$ is $Y$" can be understood to mean "every example of $X$ is an example of $Y$, and every example of $Y$ is an example of $X$".  That is, $X=Y$.  I am struggling to come up with good, non-mathematical English, examples of this interpretation (which, perhaps, indicates that this is not the usual vernacular interpretation).  For example

  - one and one *is* two (i.e. $1+1=2$),
  - a $90^\circ$ angle *is* a right angle (in a context where angle measure are restricted to less than $180^\circ$)

Of course, the real point is that "Less is More" is not meant to be a mathematical statement, and I would regard *either* interpretation (either "$\textrm{less} \subseteq \text{more}$" or "$\textrm{less} = \text{more}$") as incorrect.  The intended meaning is likely something more akin to "saying less has more impact"; the idea being that by editing something down or trimming out the fat, you produce a stronger end result.  But that would be a question for [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).